# Is there an equivalent to CTRL+C in IPython Notebook in Firefox to break cells that are running?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've started to use the IPython Notebook and am enjoying it. Sometimes, I write buggy code that takes massive memory requirements or has an infinite loop. I find the "interrupt kernel" option sluggish or unreliable, and sometimes I have to restart the kernel, losing everything in memory.

I also sometimes write scripts that cause OS X to run out of memory, and I have to do a hard reboot. I'm not 100% sure, but when I've written bugs like this before and ran Python in the terminal, I can usually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> my scripts.

I am using the Anaconda distribution of IPython notebook with Firefox on Mac OS X.

Comment: I've never been successful at interrupting an infinite loop via the cntrl+m i shortcut or the kernel>interrupt dropdown in 0.13 (default for anaconda on MacOSX). The problem seems to be fixed in 1.0.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the "interrupt kernel" button just sends a SIGINT signal to the code that you're currently running (this idea is supported by Fernando's comment [here](http://lighthouseinthesky.blogspot.com/2011/09/review-ipython-notebooks.html)), which is the same thing that hitting CTRL+C would do. Some processes within python handle SIGINTs more abruptly than others.

If you desperately need to stop something that is running in iPython Notebook and you started iPython Notebook from a terminal, you can hit CTRL+C twice in that terminal to interrupt the entire iPython Notebook server. This will stop iPython Notebook alltogether, which means it won't be possible to restart or save your work, so this is obviously not a great solution (you need to hit CTRL+C twice because it's a safety feature so that people don't do it by accident). In case of emergency, however, it generally kills the process more quickly than the "interrupt kernel" button.

Comment: Alternatively, you could restart or stop the offending kernel - less drastic than killing the ipython server. This can be done from the `Kernel` dropdown or from the notebook server's page (the `Shutdown` button to the right of the offending notebook's name).

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the browser can become so unresponsive, that it is hard to reach the server page.

Comment: Is there a way to interrupt a process in `jupyter-console`? II/control-c doesnt work. And there is no other shortcut to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 91):

You can press `I` twice to interrupt the kernel.

This only works if you're in Command mode. If not already enabled, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enable it.

Comment: Is this for a specific version range of IPython or a specific OS?

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/notebook.html#keyboard-shortcuts) are shortcuts for the IPython Notebook.

`Ctrl-m i` interrupts the kernel. (that is, the sole letter i after `Ctrl-m`)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38229513/175036) answer, `I` twice works as well.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the above: If interrupt is not working, you can restart the kernel.

Go to the kernel dropdown >> restart >> restart and clear output. This usually does the trick. If this still doesn't work, kill the kernel in the terminal (or task manager) and then restart.

Interrupt doesn't work well for all processes. I especially have this problem using the R kernel.

Comment: This trick did it for me: totally unresponsive Jupyter Notebook due to multi core kmeans clustering of 2 Billion entries (should have known before)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: Turned my solution into a stand-alone python script.

This solution has saved me more than once. Hopefully others find it useful. This python script will find any jupyter kernel using more than `cpu_threshold` CPU and prompts the user to send a `SIGINT` to the kernel (KeyboardInterrupt). It will keep sending `SIGINT` until the kernel's cpu usage goes below `cpu_threshold`. If there are multiple misbehaving kernels it will prompt the user to interrupt each of them (ordered by highest CPU usage to lowest). A big thanks goes to [gcbeltramini](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1000#issuecomment-359875246) for writing code to find the name of a jupyter kernel using the jupyter api. This script was tested on MACOS with python3 and requires jupyter notebook, requests, json and psutil.

Put the script in your home directory and then usage looks like:

```
python ~/interrupt_bad_kernels.py
Interrupt kernel chews cpu.ipynb; PID: 57588; CPU: 2.3%? (y/n) y
```

Script code below:

```
from os import getpid, kill
from time import sleep
import re
import signal

from notebook.notebookapp import list_running_servers
from requests import get
from requests.compat import urljoin
import ipykernel
import json
import psutil


def get_active_kernels(cpu_threshold):
    """Get a list of active jupyter kernels."""
    active_kernels = []
    pids = psutil.pids()
    my_pid = getpid()

    for pid in pids:
        if pid == my_pid:
            continue
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            cmd = p.cmdline()
            for arg in cmd:
                if arg.count('ipykernel'):
                    cpu = p.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)
                    if cpu > cpu_threshold:
                        active_kernels.append((cpu, pid, cmd))
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
            continue
    return active_kernels


def interrupt_bad_notebooks(cpu_threshold=0.2):
    """Interrupt active jupyter kernels. Prompts the user for each kernel."""

    active_kernels = sorted(get_active_kernels(cpu_threshold), reverse=True)

    servers = list_running_servers()
    for ss in servers:
        response = get(urljoin(ss['url'].replace('localhost', '127.0.0.1'), 'api/sessions'),
                       params={'token': ss.get('token', '')})
        for nn in json.loads(response.text):
            for kernel in active_kernels:
                for arg in kernel[-1]:
                    if arg.count(nn['kernel']['id']):
                        pid = kernel[1]
                        cpu = kernel[0]
                        interrupt = input(
                            'Interrupt kernel {}; PID: {}; CPU: {}%? (y/n) '.format(nn['notebook']['path'], pid, cpu))
                        if interrupt.lower() == 'y':
                            p = psutil.Process(pid)
                            while p.cpu_percent(interval=0.1) > cpu_threshold:
                                kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
                                sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interrupt_bad_notebooks()
```

Comment: Code above is lovely, however it has a flaw that do not consider zombie processes.

Just used in a Mac M1 and had a few errors, so I’d insert inside get active kernel the following:


except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        continue
    except psutil.ZombieProcess:
        continue

right after the except psutil.AccesDenied exception.


This will make it run perfectly.