# Jupyter notebook stuck in pdb mode

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdb, ipdb

I'm using Jupyter (IPython) notebook, where pdb / ipdb runs fine, except for one problem: If I accidentally run the same cell that my pdb is in while in pdb mode, the output disappears, the entire notebook gets stuck and I can't run any more commands. I also tried interrupting or restarting the kernel; doesn't work. My only option is to shut down the notebook, and restart it.

Does anyone else experience this problem / know of a solution? Very annoying for me to have to restart the notebook every time I make this mistake.

Here are screenshots of the problem. Below I'm in pdb mode as expected:

[image]

If I then (accidentally) run the same cell my pdb is in, the notebook gets stuck trying to run that cell, and won't run anything else (like the cell below).

[image]

Comment: 'Kernel -> Interrupt' (or Restart) to exit out of the `pdb` loop. You should `q(uit)` pdb if you want your kernel to continue running before running another cell.

Comment: Restart works but Interrupt does not unfortunately (at least for me). Yes, quitting pdb is obviously what I want to do but the question is for if I run the pdb cell accidentally (which happens surprisingly often...), in which case the pdb input bar disappears.

Comment: See [Problems with shell commands (magic) expecting output · Issue #10499 · ipython/ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10499) for a bug report on this.

Comment: See this Github issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10516

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Jupyter (mine is `6.1.4`), pressing the "Interrupt kernel" button solves the problem (and you keep all your variables and your python session):

[image]

Pressing the button after you re-run the cell yielding the break point, you again get the `pdb` console printed to the output of the cell where you then can interact with `pdb` again. It seems that the "Interrupt kernel" works like a Keyboard interrupt, forcing the output cell to refresh.

Pressing `i` twice after the re-run has the same effect (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38229513/6047357)).

Comment: This does not appear to work if you have deleted the cell that produced the PDB console.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to restart.
Click on the menu "Kernel", select "Restart" and click on the button "Restart".
Now, re-execute your cell.

Comment: Looks like it works but I lose my variables - guess there's no better way?

Comment: Not that I know of.  A simple interrupt does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Type <kbd>c</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue execution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think his problem is that he cannot enter something into the console opened by `pdb` as he rerun the cell.

Comment: @Wondercricket The answer doesn’t really contain code, and screenshots seem entirely appropriate in this case (that said, I suspect Tobias is right).